# Wordpress Custom CSS not applying correctly in browser

Tags: css, wordpress

I am trying to save custom css in wordpress (Customize -> Additional CSS), but it is not applying correctly when I press Publish and reload the page.

If I open devtools, I can see there is a syntax error in the #wp-custom-css about halfway through when I had a media query. Since the brackets are not closed, the CSS thereafter is not parsed properly.

```css
@media screen and (width.mh-container {
```

should be

```css
@media screen and (width<=500px) {
```

I looked in the database and it is saving it correctly, which makes sense since every time I reopen the Additional CSS window it brings the correct version. If I add a space then remove it so it is reapplying the additional CSS to the current page preview, everything works correctly.

Comment: as a quick fix, I put the custom css in a theme css file and it loads it OK. but I would rather be able to edit it in the customize css window

Comment: If `<=500px)` becomes `.mh-container`, that'd be a problem with more than just unclosed brackets though ...? Is `.mh-container` occurring somewhere later in the CSS you are injecting? My suspicion here would be that it does not get escaped properly when output into the page, and that therefor the `<` messes things up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try the standard format (I've never tried using `<=` in a media query, nor seen it anywhere before):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

    //css rules

}
```

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.php

Comment: Thanks, it works now! `width<=X` is too fresh in CSS and I think it's a wordpress bug to not apply it.

Comment: ...if it's a new rule, it may not be supported yet. Anyway, glad it worked.